# flutter run problem and a white screen appearing over chrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

i am runing in chrome but UI is not visible on screen

[image]

i have check flutter doctor,pub-get
and run

Comment: When you are running on the browser, errors are shown in the developer tools. Check the error in the chrome by opening developer tools with the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+I, check console or network tab. Hope this will help to find out error, in other case please post your developer tab error